# How to work with FadeIn and FadeOut the playback music using iphone sdk

Tags: ios4, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am implementing an audio based application, in my application I need to integrate FadeIn and FadeOut feature.

What I need to do is I need to use down the volume level of the music player when an audio of the application is started with high volume level. Is this possible?

Thank you,
Chandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its 5 months since you asked this question but still here is my answer.

I tried a rather stupid technique. I decreased the volume of the player by 0.1 recursively till it reached from 1.0 to 0.0. When it became 0.0 I stopped the player. It gave me a fade out effect. I hope this helps you. If you find a better way to do it, please do share it with me.